# Is a function definition not allowed here before a '{' token?

Tags: c++

I am creating a game, and I have this code. However, it is not working:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_ITEMS = 100;
bool running = 1;
int playerInfo[2];
void titleFunc();
int userInput = 0;

void newGameFunc();

int main() {
    titleFunc();
    newGameFunc();
    int playerLocation = 0;
    while (running) {

    }

    if (playerLocation == 1) {
        cout << "You are in a dungeon. You have just woke up from escaping the execution of your father. You see a pathway to the North, and a large gaping hole to the South.\n";
        cout << "1. Go South\n 2. Go North";
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput == 1) 
            playerLocation = 2;
        else 
            if (userInput == 2) 
                playerLocation = 3;
    }
    return 0;

    titleFunc() {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t---Fantasee---\n\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t     1:Play\n";

        cin >> userInput;

        if (userInput == 1) {
            newGameFunc();
        }
        else {
            running = 0;
        }
        return;
    }

    newGameFunc() {
        cout << "Welcome to Fantasee, a world of adventure and danger. \n";
        cout << "To begin, please enter your gender: \n 1. Male 2. Female";
        cin >> userInput;
        playerInfo[0] = userInput;

        cout << "And what class do you wish to be? \n 1. Wizard 2. Archer 3. Warrior 4. Trickster 5. Knight 6. Assassin";
        cin >> userInput;
        playerInfo[1] = userInput;
        playerLocation = 1;
        return;
    }
}

}
}
```

And I am getting the error message:

> g++ Main.cpp -o Main 
>   Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
>   Main.cpp:36:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token 
>   Main.cpp:67:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input 
>    
>   Edit: Wrong Error Message 
>   Edited code to current.

Comment: Change `void newGameFunc();` to `newGameFunc();`. The first one is **declaration** the second one is a **call**. Then also forward declare it like you did for the `titleFunck()`

Comment: Forward decalre it like you did for `titleFunc`. Above main. Or just move the whole function above main.

Comment: This worked, but I still have:
Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cpp:36:18: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
Main.cpp:67:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

Comment: Does your code really look like that? If so, then you are making life hard for yourself. If you cannot lay it out yourself, get a program to do so. Indent and space it properly.

Comment: Your error message suggests that you've added a closing brace in `main` some time between compiling and posting your code. I get `<stdin>: In function ‘void titleFunc()’:
<stdin>:40:21: error: ‘newGameFunc’ was not declared in this scope
<stdin>: In function ‘void newGameFunc()’:
<stdin>:58:5: error: ‘playerLocation’ was not declared in this scope
`

Comment: Main.cpp:36:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
is another error I am getting.

Comment: Oh gawd the indentation

Comment: I hate these moving target questions. How about reducing the code to a minimal test cast of one thing that you think should work but doesn't?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are declaring the function bodies inside the main function, which is not valid. Also you've been using too many '}'-s.

Your code should look more like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_ITEMS = 100;

bool running = 1;

int playerInfo[2];

void titleFunc();

int userInput = 0;
int playerLocation = 0;

void newGameFunc();

void titleFunc() {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t---Fantasee---\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t     1:Play\n";

    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == 1) {

        newGameFunc();

    }
    else {
        running = 0;
    }
    return;
}

void newGameFunc() {
    cout << "Welcome to Fantasee, a world of adventure and danger. \n";
    cout << "To begin, please enter your gender: \n 1. Male 2. Female";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[0] = userInput;

    cout << "And what class do you wish to be? \n 1. Wizard 2. Archer 3. Warrior 4. Trickster 5. Knight 6. Assassin";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[1] = userInput;
    playerLocation = 1;
    return;
}

int main() {

    titleFunc();

    newGameFunc();

    while (running) {

    }
    if (playerLocation == 1){
        cout << "You are in a dungeon. You have just woke up from escaping the execution of your father. You see a pathway to the North, and a large gaping hole to the South.\n";
        cout << "1. Go South\n 2. Go North";
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput == 1) playerLocation = 2;
        else if (userInput == 2) playerLocation = 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw I guess you also should have the if-block inside the while loop, otherwise you'll get nothing but an infinite loop.