# C++ [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token, I`m trying to change the tables in strcpy into pointers

Tags: c++

So I have this strcpy with tables but I need to change it so that there's no tables and only pointers. When I try to do it, there's an error (I put $$ in front)

So the original:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
        
int main() {
char *mon_strcpy(char destination[], char source[]) {
    int index = 0;
    while (source[index] != '\0') {
       destination[index] = source[index];
       index++;
    }
    destination[index] = '\0';
    return destination;
}
return 0;
}
```

And this is the one I'm trying to make it work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
        
int main() {
    char *mon_strcpy(char *destination, char *source) $${
        int index = 0;
        while (*source != '\0') 
        {
           *destination = *source;
           index++;
        }
        *destination = '\0';
        return destination;   
    }
return 0;
}
```

I can't wrap my head around to find the problem.. TIA

Comment: "When I try to do it, there's an error (I put $$ in front)" **Please don't do this**. Show the code that you actually have; don't try to mark it up. In order to explain the error, **show** the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message, by copying and pasting it, formatted like code.

Comment: The original has the same error.

Comment: A few results from a search for `[c++] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token`: [Is a function definition not allowed here before a '{' token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185288/) and [Error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token at line 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910361/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C & C++, you have to declare-define a function outside the other function (here `main()`). Something like:

```
char *mon_strcpy(char *destination, char *source) { ... }

int main () { 
  mon_strcpy(dst, src);
}
```

Also `$$` sign is not allowed to be used inside C++ code except comments.
This just addresses the compiler error you have.

If you have a problem with the function logic, why is it not working? You may want to debug followed by a new question.

Comment: Uh, Thanks! I tried and it worked! Is the code in itself is ok with the pointers (if it's outside of the main)? I'm not sure about the way I made it in pointers other than tables..

Comment: @AnnieMissPomme, if your error got fixed, you may accept this answer by clicking the "right tick" near my post. I am not sure if your existing code can work as it has lot of open area & issues; e.g. what are the sizes of memory allocated to pointers OR are they on stack and so on. It's worth a new separate question.